Freeswitch Lua API - how to get Channel State?
Using Freeswitch, I am desperately trying to get the channel Call State value in Lua.
The Lua script is executed by posting an HTTP request to Verto..
This is the Lua code I have, so far:
api  = freeswitch.API()
uuid = api:executeString("create_uuid")
[... some blablabla code....]
dialstr = "{uuid=" ... uuid ...",caller_id_number=" ... callerId ... " ....." and so on

ret = api:execute("originate", dialstr)
con = freeswitch.EventComsumer("all")
check = true
while check do
   event = con:pop(1)
   event_name = event:getHeader("Event-Name")
   print(event_name)
   event_state = event:getHeader("Channel-Call-State")
   print(event_state)
end -- end while


The above lines will fail when printing event_state because
event_state is nil, but event_name will correctly show up.
Changing to:

event_state = api:execute_string("eval uuid:" .. uuid .. " ${Channel-Call-State}"

Will always return early!
Any explanation for this behaviour? How can I get the call state using Lua and the Freeswitch API? I need to check when the call is ringing, answered, busy, congestion, hangup, etc.... until it is in the reporting state (and access CDR).

session:getState();
or
execute_on_ring
execute_on_media
execute_on_answer

You can improve your answer by explaining it.  Pretend you are a teacher.
